# Regex remove entire Line by matching everything that is not like the other Lines

Tags: regex

I've written a regex to remove every line that does not look like the lines I want to keep :

```
^((?![0-9]{18},.*\],.*).)*$
```

The problem I have is that it leaves empty lines, which I would like to avoid. I played around with the `\n` and put in on every possible position but it just doesn't match.

This is my Python code :

```
with io.open('sample_test.txt', 'w', encoding="utf-8") as f, io.open('sample_test1.txt', encoding="utf-8") as g: 
    for line in g:
                c = re.sub(r'^((?![0-9]{18},.*\],.*).)*$', r'', line.rstrip())
                print (c, file = f)
f.close()
g.close()
```

Any idea?

Comment: Any example input and output you expect ?

Comment: For exemple this would be matched: 709913309693214720,,@wesleyfinn8 your

Comment: It matches everything that I want I just don't know how to get it deleted and I mean the entire Line

Comment: what does the main application use ? java, c++, php, python ?

Comment: I am trying to do that in Notepad++. But after I want to use it in a python script

Comment: BTW regex doesn't remove the line, it matches a line. You need to call a replace API to replace it. What is your exact question?

Comment: I know I replaced it with nothing '' but it keeps still an empty line in the text and I want to get ride of that line so I dont havy any empty lines in my file

Comment: Please show your code to replace in python.

Comment: It gives me this for some reason but i dont know why c = re.sub(r'^((?![0-9]{18},.*\],.*).)*$', r'', line.rstrip())
                                                                 ^
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation

Comment: Instead of trying to replace, test each line with `[0-9]{18},[^\]]*]` and print it only if you have a match.

Comment: actualy a good Idea I will try that :D

Comment: You can try putting (\r\n)* at the end. Then, when you replace it with nothing, it should also remove the new line.